# SQL - converting continuos numbers to a range

Tags: sql

Is there a way to convert continuos numbers from one column into a range? F.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, into 1 - 4? I know that it can be done with MIN and MAX, but how can it be done when there are numbers missing in the string, and I need ranges of continuos values? F.e 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 into 1 - 3 and 5 - 7?

Comment: Can you add a tag to indicate which DBMS implementation are you trying to do this in?  The tag "sql" applies to Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and others.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `CASE` expression, e.g.

```sql
SELECT
    val,
    CASE WHEN val BETWEEN 1 AND 4  THEN '1 - 4'
         WHEN val BETWEEN 5 AND 10 THEN '5 - 10'
         ELSE 'other' END AS the_range
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: The OP's target is not this that checking value is in a specific range. He/She wants to build up a 1 column data shows the distribution of values.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use a trick where you subtract a sequence from the values.  The difference is constant for incrementing values.  Then aggregate:

```
select min(val), max(val)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by val) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by (val - seqnum);
```

You can format the min and max however you like.